# Differential equations - bounded dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$-function and let $I_{x_0}=(a,b)$. Assume that there exist $M>0$ such that $|\varphi(\cdot,x_0)|_{[0,b)}|\le M$, where $\varphi(t,x)$ is dynamical system generated by equation $x'=f(x)$. How to show that $b=+\infty$ and there exist $\lim_{t\to\infty}\varphi(t,x_0)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Any solution to $\dot x=f(x)$ is a monotone function.

Comment: Why ? We only know that $f$ is $C^1$ - why $f$ must be constantly positive/negative ?

Comment: @mikis Hint #2: Let $\hat{x}$ be such that $f(\hat{x})=0$. Then $t\mapsto \hat{x}$ solves $\dot x=f(x)$.